# How to get a child element to show behind (lower z-index) than its parent?

Tags: html, css, dom, z-index

I need a certain dynamic element to always appear on top of another element, no matter what order in the DOM tree they are. Is this possible? I've tried `z-index` (with `position: relative`), and it doesn't seem to work.

I need:

```html
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="b">
        <div class="a"></div>
    </div>
```

To display exactly the same when rendered. And for flexibility purposes (I'm planning on distributing a plugin that needs this functionality), I'd really like to not have to resort to absolute or fixed positioning.

For what it's worth, to perform the function I was wanting, I made a conditional statement where the overlapping child element would become transparent in the case it was blocking the view of its parent. It's not perfect, but it's something.

Comment: This _is_ possible - assuming you only have nesting of 1 level deep (as in the example). This will work:  `.a > .b, .b > .a {z-index: -1; position: relative}`. If you need a fiddle, comment, but I think it's pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If the elements make a hierarchy, it cannot be done that way, because every positioned element creates new [stacking context](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex), and z-index is relative to the elements of the same stacking context.

Comment: I pretty much thought this was the case, but I don't presume to know everything. Either way, thanks all.

Comment: although this is the accepted answer, (maybe this answer was correct at the time? but) this is not true -- see other answers for ways to get child behind parent.  (I just did it accidentally, where I had previously assumed it was impossible, and found this question while searching to find how it happened)

Comment: If you set the z-index of the child to -1, then it goes behind it's parent element

Answer (score 54):

You can do this in modern browsers now using transform 3D with CSS. It wasn't really possible in 2010 but it is now.

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  transform: translateZ(-10px)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Parent
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have fixed it so the code is more obvious.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out a way to actually put the child element behind its element by creating a pseudo-element which mimics the parent. Useful for stuff like dropdown-menus - hope it helps, user from eight years ago!

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
 .container > div {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}
 .container > div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 7;
  top: 10px;
}
 .a > .b, .b > .a {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
}
 .a + .b {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="b">
    <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer for the question

> *How to get a child element to show behind (lower z-index) than its parent?*

is to:

- Make the parent **not a `stacking context`**
- Make the child a `positioned stacking context`, whose z-index smaller than 0.

Notice: I said *make the child a **positioned stacking context***,
   not just **stacking context**, because pay attention that [z-index will only be valid for **positioned** element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index#wikiArticle))

About how an element is considered a *stacking context*, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context#The_stacking_context), and how an element is considered a positioned element, read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Types_of_positioning). Or a great explanation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903621/9787887).

---

**Conclusion:**

- Make sure the parent *is not a stacking context*
- Make sure the child *is a stacking context*
- Make sure the *child's `z-index` is smaller than 0*
- Make sure the child *is a positioned element* so that the `z-index` from last step is applicable

Yet you have to understand 2 terms [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context#The_stacking_context) and [positioned element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Types_of_positioning)

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using the following.

z-index: -1;

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked

Comment: Upvoted, this does not deserve a downvote. This _partially_ answers the question being asked - it would be better if he demonstrated with a fiddle.

Comment: This does deserve a downvote because it is incorrect. The question specifies getting a child element to display behind its parent using z-index and without using absolute positioning. As jholster has explained it cannot be achieved this with these conditions.

Comment: For fixed positioning of both child and parent element it works. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
.element--child{
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is `position: absolute` in order for z-index to work.

also you will need to set the `left` and `top` css properties to position the element in the correct place. You will probably need to do this with javascript.

Comment: z-index works for positioned (= relative, absolute, fixed), i.e. non-static elements.

Comment: Or `position: fixed;` ^_^