# CSS :after behind parent element

Tags: css, z-index, behind

Is it possible to get a CSS pseudo `:after` element behind the background of it's parent element?

The background of the `:after` contains equal dimensions as the parent element's background. So currently it looks like this:

[image]

But I want the red background (`:after`) to go behind the parent element. 
So I've added `position: relative` to the parent and `absolute` to the pseudo element.

Trying to archive this I've used this code:

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .8rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background: #000;
}

.btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -0.3rem; right: -0.3rem;
  z-index: -1;

  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  content:'';
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn">
  This is my button
</a>
```

The weird thing is that above snippet works like charm. But in my [live example](http://www.capybaras.nl/) the exact same code displays as the image in this topic.. Someone knows what is wrong in the live site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your website, you have the following CSS rule:

```
.btn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .8rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

If you remove the `z-index: 1` property, your CSS will work correctly.
This property is not in the sample snippet that you provided above.

I tried it out using CSS inspector in Firefox and that seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the z-index in my live site later to see if it could make any difference. I'll have to put another z-index on the parent container of the button to make it work like you site instead of on the button itself. Problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You **can** place the `:after` element behind its parent if you wrap its parent inside another element. What happens is that the `:after` is ignoring the positioning on its parent, but it will apply positioning on the next parent in the hierarchy.

HTML

```
    <div class="wrap">
        <a href="" class="btn blue">
            <span>Bekijk op facebook</span>
            <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.btn{
    /* remove position:relative; */
}
```

But, box-shadow solution in timothym answer, would be a bit more suitable for this specific case, not sure how would that fit with the rest of your website.

Answer (score 4):

A `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element is considered a [child element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter), and due to the stacking context of the elements, an `:after` element can't be [displayed behind its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503705/html-get-a-child-element-to-show-behind-lower-z-index-than-its-parent) in this way.

However, you can use `box-shadow` to create a solid 'border' that achieves the effect you are going for. Here's an example:

```
.btn{
  box-shadow: red 6px 7px 0 0;
}
```