# Stack Parent of Pseudo Elements on Top

Tags: html, css

I have an element with two pseudo elements, `:before` and `:after`. The parent is positioned relative with `z-index: 0`, and the two pseudo elements are positioned absolute with `z-index: -1`.

However, I can't get the parent element to stack on top. How can I fix this?

Here's a codepen illustrating the issue: http://codepen.io/zthall/pen/NNmKgZ

The SCSS code:

```
.pokeball {
  height: $size / 5;
  width: $size / 5;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: ($size / 20) solid $black;
  position: relative;
  margin: ($size * 4 / 5);
  z-index: 1;

  &:after, 
  &:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: $size;
    height: $size / 2;
    border-radius: $size $size 0 0;
    border: ($size / 20) solid $black;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
  }

  &:after {
    background: $red;
    top: -$size / 2;
    left: -$size / 2;
  }

  &:before {
    background: $white;
    top: 0;
    left: -$size / 2;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="pokeball"></div>
```

Comment: `z-index: 0` makes the parent establish a stacking context, and then it's not possible. Just remove that. Possible duplicate of [CSS :after behind parent element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34190157/1529630) or [HTML: Get a child element to show behind (lower z-index) than its parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2503705/1529630)

Comment: Thanks, @Oriol. Interestingly now it just disappears during the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two semicircle elements with the pseudo `:before` and `:after` elements, you can use a linear and radial gradient to fill the circles.

http://codepen.io/zthall/pen/KzYKJZ